# Floating foam organized in circles

Tags: everyday-life, vibrations

I was walking by the kitchen when I saw the bowl in which my mom had put some beans in water to soak before cooking them. The thing is that I saw these concentric circles made out of the foam/bubbles floating in the water.

[image: Circles]

All of the bowls showed the circles but this was the most clear one.

What is causing it? I thought that maybe something felt by the beans in the water made it vibrate but after trying again from zero the circle formed again without anything falling in i. Also, I didn't find anything other than beans and water in it and it's hard to think something would fall in the middle of the bowl.

Is there another explanation to the organization of the foam? Is it all in my head??